# Possible to make a switchless install from a password protected archive?

Tags: encryption, archiving, 7-zip, installer

I am using 7-zip to make a switchless install (method for doing so [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/39048-how-to-make-a-7-zip-switchless-installer/) and [here](http://coderdan.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-7-zip-switchless-installer.html)).  I would like to use a password protected archive to make said install to help prevent the average user from simply unzipping the archive (yes, I do realize that password protected archives are not terribly secure, I'm just trying to prevent the average user from unzipping).  Is this possible to do?  When I've tried to do this I just get an error box saying "Unsupported Method".  Is there some way to specify the password for the archive while making the executable file (probably in the config file)?

Comment: Actually password protected archives are VERY secure, assuming you choose decent algorithms.  regardless of that, if they can just run it to decrypt/decompress it, what's the point of password protecting it? The "average user" can double-click icons. :)

Comment: Well, the idea is that since we are giving the installer config options in command line arguments that are specific to that user we don't really want them pulling setup.exe out of the archive and running it without those custom arguments / configs and then having to support them as they try to "fix" their installation.  I guess "average user" was not the proper descriptor, should probably have said "the average curious technically inclined user" ;-)